# What is the role of the key in a Google Photos Album url?

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

Go to your Google Photos Albums page and hover over an album thumbnail. You'll see that an album's url looks like this:

```
https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipN2T_IX-a4TjilksiuioY12GFNF59N-zaZQpz5vrD-QStk5C3FaLDJ1c5s1p_SJUJY5kA?key=MF9WbC0zRmpVZFQxTk9hT1lWdGVjUjV4UzRFbE
```

Does anybody know the role of the key?

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't say exactly what the key's role is, but it's
a start.

Without the key, the url will open the album only for its owner.
With the key, the url will open the album for anyone, non-owners.
The non-owner will only have the right to look, not to edit.